# Adjusting display for screens CSS

Tags: html, css, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to change `display: inline-flex` to `display: inline-block` in CSS when the screen is smaller. But It doesn't change anything.
This is the code:

```
.about{display: inline-flex}
@small screen and (max: 600px){.about{display:inline-block}}
```

Comment: you got an answer below you need to look more on the media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries to learn more about it. Look at zielvna 's answer thats how you do it. Please accept the answer so this case is solved.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your syntax. You need to change `@small` to `@media` and `(max: 600px)` to `(max-width: 600px)`. Here is the code:

```
.about {
    display: inline-flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .about {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```